# entityFieldQuery not returning term references - not in field_data but are in field_revision

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

So, I'm pretty new to drupal(7) - any help here greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is use entityFieldQuery to return a list of nodes that have a given term in them.

I have a field, "field_crafts", where crafts is a term reference, and points to a specific vocabulary. I also have a 'tags' field.

If I use fieldCondition('field_tags', 'tid', $n), the entityFieldQuery works fine, and returns all nodes with the given tag.

But if I do the very same thing on field_crafts instead, it returns no results.

I've poked around in my database, and it appears that field_data_field_tags table has data in it, but the field_data_field_crafts does not. However, the field_revision_field_crafts table does. And when I load up the node in the UI, it does indeed remember which terms I have ticked in the list of checkboxes.

So, what's going on here? I imagine that if the crafts data were just to appear in the data table, the query would work fine. Why isn't it, and is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: So, having moved on to other things on my site, it seems like none of my entityFieldQueries are returning the most recent revision of the entity, they instead use the oldest -- presumably this is really where the problem lies. But how to fix it...?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was going on -- I was using the 'moderation' plugin and so all the changes I was making were secretly getting marked as 'draft' despite me making the changes as an admin. Doh.